# PHP display an ACF post which has different fields to its sibling posts

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have 5 Galleries which are created using a Custom Post Type in Advanced Custom Fields. ONE of my galleries has a different set of fields from the other galleries. The reason for this is that I need to display an image and describe that image (and repeat for several images). I have used a Repeater field to do so for each image.

The code to display my other Galleries which simply feature the WYSIWYG and a Gallery field is as follows:

```
    if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
      echo get_the_title();
      echo get_the_content(); 

      //Display images from Gallery Field
      $images = get_field('gallery_images');
          if( $images ): 
              foreach( $images as $image ): 
                  echo $image['url']; 
              endforeach; 
          endif;
```

How can I display the fields for my special gallery based on its individual post name or slug (which is Albums)

My repeater field is called album_information and it's sub fields are 'album_title', 'album_image' and 'album_description'.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/#template-usage

In your case:

```
if( have_rows('album_information') ) {
    while ( have_rows('album_information') ) {
        the_row();
        the_sub_field('album_title');
        the_sub_field('album_image');
        the_sub_field('album_description');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I had figured that bit out just as you replied. I also needed the following beforehand:                   
                        $args = array( 
                             'post_type' => 'post_type_gallery',
                             'p'  => '1748', //id of the post
                        );
                        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );